# debugging pthreads with gdb

Tags: gdb, pthreads, mutex, conditional-breakpoint

I'm trying to debug a very infrequent deadlock and I've narrowed it down to a problem with a pthread_mutex, which is of type 1 (recursive). I want to track down where this mutex is coming from and since all of our code uses normal mutexes, I thought it would make sense to detect when mutex type == recursive to trace it back.

I've tried setting a manual breakpoint in pthread_mutex_lock, dereferencing pthread_mutex_t via the stack pointer etc. to examine its type, but this is called millions of times and it would take forever to catch the case where mutex type == recursive.

I also tried interposing a library and replacing pthread_mutex_lock to make setting a breakpoint on the mutex type possible, but this didn't get any hits (not convinced this was catching all the calls to pthread_mutex_lock)

I get the feeling there must be a way in gdb of setting a watchpoint / conditional breakpoint for whenever pthread_mutex_lock is called with a mutex of type recursive?

Any help on the above would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> I've narrowed it down to a problem with a pthread_mutex, which is of type 1 (recursive) ... 
>   I want to track down where this mutex is coming from and since all of our code uses normal mutexes

Presumably you've somehow determined that your thread(s) are blocked in `pthread_mutex_lock` trying to lock a recursive mutex, and you don't understand who is holding this mutex, and why.

The stack trace leading to `pthread_mutex_lock` should tell you *exactly* which code is trying to lock that mutex, which is all you should have to know to understand the problem.

I don't understand why you want to "catch" the pthread_mutex_lock in the act of locking that mutex, as that will likely *not* give you any more info than what you already have by looking at the stack after you've detected the deadlock.

In general, trying to debug mutex locking issues with GDB is futile -- the act of setting the breakpoints (or even just attaching GDB) changes timing of the operations to such an extent, that most issues never show up when running under GDB.

Comment: I take your point, but unfortunately the stack traces appear incomplete/ corrupt (lots of ??'s) for the threads at the point of deadlock, so I can't see back enough frames to determine the code paths followed by each thread to get there (I may need to learn more about manually tracing stack pointers to do this). I agree the deadlock is unlikely to show up under gdb, however, I'm thinking tracing the origins of the recursive mutex (during normal operation) may well give me better idea of where Thread 3 is acquiring the lock (depending on how many code paths are using recursive mutexes :) ).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `gdb` breakpoints, you can use watchpoints

Comment: Thank you. Yes, watchpoints would work, but the bit I'm unsure of is how to work out the memory address to watch in order to monitor all calls to pthread_mutex_lock with type recursive.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
(gdb) conditional yourbreakpointid mutex.__m_kind==PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE
```

Where `mutex` is the name of the mutex in the scope and `yourbreakpointid` the id of the breakpoint you placed in the function.

The __m_kind may change name depending on the implementation, search your distribution headers (pthread.h)if this one doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried this, but for some reason gdb was unable to resolve the mutex parameter (can't remember the exact error message and I don't have access to my machine til Tuesday). I will try this again though, sounds like it should work.

Comment: I can't get gdb to interpret the mutex parameter passed to pthread_mutex_lock. The problem is that the parameter passed is "mutex" but when I'm in pthread_lock_mutex and I do ptype mutex, it returns std::mutex, so I get "Attempt to use a type name as an expression" when I try to do anything with it. I originally thought this might have been a gdb bug, but I'm now running the latest, still no joy. I also tried linking pthreads statically to no avail! Any help much appreciated :) !

Comment: @user1621986 Have you tried to use `::mutex`, to tell gdb this is not the `std::mutex` you are referring to, but the variable in the global namespace ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - still no joy. Strangely, in gdb if I do ptype pthread_mutex_lock it returns int (void) - don't know why this is the case (it's on redhat 5.6) I would expect to see the pthread_mutex_t argument in there. I might try a different machine and see what I get.